# Why the top margin looks more than 1.75"? and putting the abstract page inside a document in overleaf

Tags: margins, abstract

Here is the code I have:

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}

\usepackage[margin= 1 in]{geometry}


    \addtolength{\topmargin}{1.75in}
    \addtolength{\textheight}{- .1 in}
    


    %\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage{simplemargins}

%\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\Large
 \begin{center}
Simple Single Page Abstract template\\ 

\hspace{10pt}

% Author names and affiliations
\large
Arthur Author$^1$, Cecilia CoAuthor$^2$ \\

\hspace{10pt}

\small  
$^1$) First affiliation\\
arthur.author@correspondence.email.com\\
$^2$) Second affiliation

\end{center}

\hspace{10pt}

\normalsize

This is a simple one-page abstract template. Please keep your abstract length at one page. The abstract should be in English. You may include figures and pictures in your abstract, as long as they fit in the single page limit.

Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur? (Cicero, 45 BCe)
\end{document}
```

I need every margin other than the top margin to be 1" But I do not know why the top margin looks more than 1.75"(I need it to be 1.75")? Could anyone help me in adjusting this please?

Also, I want to put the abstract page to be part of my document and not the whole document, could anyone help me adjusting my code to serve this please?

Last thing, could someone help me remove the redundancy in the packages and document classes in my code please?

Comment: Loading geometry several times with different options does not make sense. I'd even expect that this example will not compile (not currently at pc so cannot test). Load Geo etry once and use the `\geometry ` command, and I'd be careful with those two addtolength

Comment: Perhaps instead you should explain what the end goal is, as it is not clear from the code

Comment: never ignore errors, if you get _any_ error, don't even look at the PDF file, fix the error, this produces  `! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package geometry.`

Comment: also what do you intend by `a4paper, total={6in, 8in}` ? The paper can be A4 size or it can be 6in by 8in but it can not be both sizes at the same time.

Comment: Can you specify, what you mean with "I want to put the abstract page to be part of my document". Do you want to insert the abstract.pdf into your main document as one page as is? In that case maybe use the `pdfpages` package. Otherwise, there may be ways using `\input` or `\include`. But it is a little hard to say without additional details.

Comment: And to actually answer your margin question: use `\usepackage[a4paper, vmargin=1in, top=1.75in, bottom = 1in]{geometry}` and you're done. On a side note: I find the use of margins in inches with A4 paper a bit awkward, because A4 paper is by definition 21cm by 29.7cm.

Comment: I am writing a thesis @MarkusG. so the first page is the abstract. Do you need more details than this?

Comment: @daleif so you are saying that the third line in my document is redundant?

Comment: @daleif what about addtolength, how should I adjust them? I need all the margins to be 1" except the top margin which I need to be 1".

Comment: @daleif I am writing my thesis and I need the paper to be $A_4,$ all of the above are my goals.

Comment: You should read the `geometry` manual. You can set the margins via `top=,bottom=,left=,right=` options for geometry. If you are a latex novice, you should never mess with things like `\topmargin` etc manually.

Comment: If you are using `A4` then why is this added `total={6in, 8in}`, your settings does not make much sense. It might be a better idea to specify in your question what exactly the end goal is. Then it is easier to help. Currently this is a mess.

Comment: Can you provide a link for geometry manual only(I mean I do not want any other packages with it) please?@daleif

Comment: @daleif Ok. I see your point.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ok, thank you!, I got your points.

Comment: @MarkusG. are you saying that I should use either margins or a4 paper? not both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as I understand the discussion from the comments, what you are looking for is probably something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[a4paper, vmargin=1in, top=1.75in, bottom = 1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    %Put whatever comes before your abstract here
    \lipsum[1]
    \newpage
    
    \newgeometry{top=1in,bottom=1in,vmargin=1in} % or whatever only your abstract is supposed to look like
    \section{Abstract}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \newpage
    
    \restoregeometry % restores the geometry from the preamble
    \lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Some comments:

1. Your page can have one size definition, so either: `a4paper`, `usletter` or `total={}`.
2. On top of that you can define margins using `top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right`. If the vertical or horizontal margins are the same you can use `hmargins` and `vmargins` instead or `margins={}` if all of the margins are identical.
3. You can use a different geometry for individual pages using `\newgeometry{}` and then `\restoregeometry`, which restores the original geometry.

Comment: I think, in my real thesis, I do not have to use the package lipsum (it is just for generating a text), is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly right. It is just hard to visualise margins in a straight forward way without something to fill the pages.

Comment: Actually, I need my abstract title to have 1.75" top margin and I need it to be the first part of my document.

Comment: The code I provided is just an example that showcases the options you have, I tried to keep it a bit more general so that it might also help other people struggling with similar issues. Feel free to adjust it however you want.

Comment: Makes complete sense